# Testing Android In App Billing v3 with Google Api?

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-billing

I am implementing a subscribing service with the google play service "In App Billing v3" in an android app. I was able to implement the subscribing service in the app and I tested it in alpha channel. Now I want to test the whole lifecycle of the subscription.

This is the idea. An user subscribe to the service with "In App Billing v3". Then the app request an api that I own, and that server request Google Api.

This is working when the user susbcribe. The problem is when the user cancel the subscription, I am not able to test this case.

Any idea how I would be able to test this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand you question, but if you want to know how to test when a subscription's active period ends and the user opts to not renew it, then you could either create mock purchases (make your app think that a subscription is active and then cancelled) or you could use Google's test subscriptions (http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#test-purchases). They last for 24 hours, so you could "buy" a test subscription, cancel it and wait 24 hours for the end of its active. It's not very productive, but if you're not willing to create a mock of google's api, then that's what you'd have to do.

Just remember that when a user cancels a subscription it will still be active until the end of its period (they did pay for the whole period after all). Only if a subscription is revoked does it end immediately.